# How to combine results in a Mongo aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm new to aggregation queries in Mongo and been really struggling trying to produce the output I want. I have the following aggregation query:

```
db.events.aggregate([
  { $match: { requestState: "APPROVED" } },
  { $unwind: { path: "$payload.description" } },
  { $group: { _id: { instr: "$payload.description", bu: "$createdByUser", count: { $sum: 1 } } } }
]);
```

that returns the following results:

```
{ "_id" : { "instr" : "ABC-123", "bu" : "BU2", "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : { "instr" : "ABC-123", "bu" : "BU1", "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : { "instr" : "DEF-456", "bu" : "BU1", "count" : 1 } }
```

How can I amend the aggregation query so that there are only 2 documents returned instead of 3? With the two "ABC-123" results combined into a single result with a new array of counts with the "bu" and "count" fields i.e.

```
{ "_id" : { "instr" : "ABC-123", "counts": [ { "bu" : "BU1", "count" : 1 }, { "bu" : "BU2", "count" : 1 } ] } }
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add another stage to only `$group` by `_id.instr` and another stage to `$project` to your desired output shape

```
db.events.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { requestState: "APPROVED" }
  },
  {
    $unwind: { path: "$payload.description" }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { instr: "$payload.description", bu: "$createdByUser", count: { $sum: 1 } }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { instr: "$_id.instr" },
      counts: { $push: { bu: "$_id.bu", count: "$_id.count" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: { instr: "$_id.instr", counts: "$counts" }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. That's great. Gives me this as output - { "_id": { "instr": "ABC-123", "counts": [ { "bu": "BU2", "count": 1 }, { "bu": "BU1", "count": 1 } ] } }. Is this giving me a counts array with two objects in it? I want to iterate over the counts array and print the "bu" value and the "count" value.

Comment: Yes it is, just like the output you specified in the question. Everything is inside _id